# Using Cobertura produces a NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: gradle, cobertura

we are using Cobertura (defined in a gradle build). When I deploy the application and click around in the swing client, there appears a NoClassDefFoundError from cobertura.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sourceforge/cobertura/coveragedata/HasBeenInstrumented
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.findClass(JNLPClassLoader.java:345)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
```

I have no clue where this is coming from. There is nothing from cobertura in my java code. The only place where cobertura is defined is in the gradle build files as dependencies:

```
testCompile "net.sourceforge.cobertura:cobertura:1.9.4.1"
```

I made a grep over the two main projects:

```
find -type f -name "*gradle*" -exec grep -Hn cobertura {} \;
```

Here the result:

```
./BigTableDataProvider/ext-test/build.gradle:7:def cobSerFile = "$buildDir/cobertura.ser"
./BigTableDataProvider/ext-test/build.gradle:24:    testCompile 'net.sourceforge.cobertura:cobertura:1.9.4.1'
./BigTableDataProvider/ext-test/build.gradle:34:    codeCoverageRun 'net.sourceforge.cobertura:cobertura:1.9.4.1'
./BigTableDataProvider/ext-test/build.gradle:42:    jvmArgs = sampleJvmArg.split(" ").toList() << "-Dnet.sourceforge.cobertura.datafile=$cobSerFile"
./BigTableDataProvider/ext-test/build.gradle:50:        'cobertura-instrument'(datafile: cobSerFile) {
./BigTableDataProvider/ext-test/build.gradle:63:    ant.'cobertura-report'(destdir: "${project.buildDirName}/reports/codeCoverage",

./BigTableExplorer/sample/server/build.gradle:10:    testCompile 'net.sourceforge.cobertura:cobertura:1.9.4.1' // Add this if sample module has inherited classes from server.
./BigTableExplorer/ext-server/build.gradle:20:    testCompile "net.sourceforge.cobertura:cobertura:1.9.4.1"
./BigTableExplorer/ext-test/build.gradle:7:def cobSerFile = "cobertura.ser"
./BigTableExplorer/ext-test/build.gradle:22:    testCompile 'net.sourceforge.cobertura:cobertura:1.9.4.1'
./BigTableExplorer/ext-test/build.gradle:34:    codeCoverageRun 'net.sourceforge.cobertura:cobertura:1.9.4.1'
./BigTableExplorer/ext-test/build.gradle:42:    jvmArgs = sampleJvmArg.split(" ").toList() << "-Dnet.sourceforge.cobertura.datafile=$cobSerFile"
./BigTableExplorer/ext-test/build.gradle:50:        'cobertura-instrument'(datafile: cobSerFile) {
./BigTableExplorer/ext-test/build.gradle:63:    ant.'cobertura-report'(destdir: "${project.buildDirName}/reports/codeCoverage",
```

Comment: Can you post your gradle build file? You say you click around in the swing client, is this your application?

Comment: It's a project with many sub-projects. Not sure which I should post. Does it help if I post a grep?

Answer (score 1):

You are accidentally deploying the Cobertura-instrumented code. The Gradle build must be using some third-party Cobertura plugin or Cobertura Ant task, and apparently it is configured incorrectly.